# How can I change the logo in Kibana?

Tags: html, css, elasticsearch

**How do I change the elastic logo from Kibana 7.13.0 to the company logo?**

my elk version : 7.13.0

**Changes made in kibana 7.13.0**

1. Change logo and title in web browser tags
2. Change the text that comes out when loading

**My goal (I attached pictures in order).**

1. Change image from loading to company logo
2. Change the elastic logo at the time of login to the company logo.
3. Change the text that appears when logging in
4. Change the elastic logo from the kibana page to the company logo
5. Change text from the kibana page

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please help me.
I googled for a week but couldn't solve it.

`I did 7.10.0 version method on the elastic homepage, but the file location is different and the directory is different.`

> Please let me know how I can change it in 7.13.0...